# How to add two registers and store in new memory location in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to create a pseudo instruction called:

```
addmem $r1, $r2, $r3
```

in which registers $r2 and $r3 have the **address** of the memory locations whose values should be added and the result should be stored in the **memory location** whose address is in $r1. How can I write this in MIPS code?

This is what I came up with:

```
lw $t2, 0($r2)
lw $t3, 0($r3)
add $t4, $t2, $t3
sw $r1, 0($t4)
```

From my understanding my code is adding load the addresses of $r2 and $r3 into $t2 and $t3 respectively. Then $4 will be the sum of these addresses and the sw instruction with set the value in the sum of the addresses to register $r1. Is this correct?

EDIT (Correct Answer):

```
    lw $t2, 0($r2)
    lw $t3, 0($r3)
    add $t4, $t2, $t3
    sw $t4, 0($r1)
```

Comment: The `sw` is wrong. Obviously `$t4` has the result and `$r1` the destination pointer so you want `sw $t4, ($r1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is everything else right? Can I add $r2 and $r3 first, use lw to load the added values to $t4, and finally store that value to $r1? It seems like that is another way.

Comment: No, you can't do that. That would add the addresses and then load a single value from that location, which is not what you want. `*a + *b` is not the same as `*(a + b)`.

Comment: Thanks! You cleared up my doubts.